# Find all ring homomorphisms from rationals to integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.
 How to solve the problem? Give me some suitable solution. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Harry Smit-set of rational to set of integers

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring-homomorphism.  Think about what you can say about $f(1/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is one such homomorphism, then for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\neq 0$,
$$
\phi(1)=\phi(a\cdot\frac{1}{a})=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(\frac{1}{a})=1
$$
Thus, since $\phi(a)$, $\phi(\frac{1}{a})$ are both integers, either $\phi(a)=\phi(\frac{1}{a})=1$ or $\phi(a)=\phi(\frac{1}{a})=-1$, for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\neq 0$.

Can you fill in the remaining details? (**Hint:** what effect would such a map  have on the additive structure? how much would $\phi(2a)$ be? Can such a  homomorphism exist?)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: there is only one (additive) *group* homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (the one that sends everything to zero). Is it a ring homomorphism?